# io ts, check if a string is in a union

Tags: typescript, validation, types, runtime-type, io-ts-library

Let's say I have the following io-ts runtimetype:

```
    const Example = t.keyof({
         'foo': null,
         'bar': null
    })
    type ExampleType = typeof Example
```

And I have an incoming request with `value: string`

How can I convert value to an `Example` (or fail and throw an exception?)

Comment: Check out the example in the third code block here: https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/dedb64e05328417ecd3d87e00008d9e72130374a/index.md.

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming isn't my strong suit, but this should get you going.

```js
import * as t from 'io-ts';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function';
import { fold } from 'fp-ts/Either';

const Example = t.keyof({
  foo: null,
  bar: null,
});
type ExampleType = typeof Example;

function toExample(value: string) {
  const exampleE = Example.decode(value);
  const example = pipe(
    exampleE,
    fold(
      (errors) => {
        const reason = errors
          .map((error) => `"${error.value}" does not match ${Example.name}`)
          .join('\n');
        throw new Error(reason);
      },
      (value) => value
    )
  );
  return example;
}

const example = toExample('foo');
console.log('value=', example);

// Will throw error
const example2 = toExample('bad');
```